# Ansible - Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,...password)

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get Ansible to connect to remote hosts but it fails with the following:

```
fatal: [prod-k8s-worker02]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: deploy@xx.xx.xx.223: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [prod-k8s-worker01]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: deploy@xx.xx.xx.222: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [prod-k8s-worker03test]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: deploy@xx.xx.xx.224: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [prod-k8s-master01]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: deploy@xx.xx.xx.221: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", "unreachable": true}
```

I can successfully `ssh` without the need of a password using the same, to all of the above hosts.

I've tried the following.

Add the following the inventory file:

```
[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=deploy
ansible_sudo=true
ansible_become=true
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

Added the following the `ansible.cfg` file:

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
host_key_check = False
```

Also added the following the `ansible.cfg` file:

```
[ssh_connection]
# ssh arguments to use
ssh_args = -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

**Verbose**

When I run in the playbook using `-vvvv` I get the following:

```
fatal: [prod-k8s-worker01]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: deploy@xx.xx.xx.222: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", 
    "unreachable": true
}
<xx.xx.xx.223> (255, '', 'deploy@xx.xx.xx.223: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n')
fatal: [prod-k8s-worker02]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: deploy@xx.xx.xx.223: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", 
    "unreachable": true
}
<xx.xx.xx.224> (255, '', 'deploy@xx.xx.xx.224: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n')
fatal: [prod-k8s-worker03test]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: deploy@xx.xx.xx.224: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", 
    "unreachable": true
}
<xx.xx.xx.221> (255, '', 'deploy@xx.xx.xx.221: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n')
fatal: [prod-k8s-master01]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: deploy@xx.xx.xx.221: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Comment: You might want to get more details about the remote host refusing the connection. If at Linux see **man sshd_config** and set "**LogLevel**".

Comment: is the `deploy` user in the sudoers? What does say `sudo -v`?

Comment: Yes, `deploy` user is in the `sudoers`. I dont have access to the server at the moment so cant answer your other question.

Comment: Can you confirm you can do ssh: deploy@xx.xx.xx.223 without error?

Comment: Run your ansible command with `-vvv`. This will show you the exact `ssh` command line that Ansible is using to connect to your remote hosts. You can use this to reproduce the problem on the command line (and it may make the issue immediately obvious).

Comment: @CalvinZhou - yes, I can ssh to that location, with the `deploy` user, without error.

Comment: I don't have much in my mind, but I would recommend you to write some simple Ansible tasks from scratch, the idea is to isolation to see if it works. If possible, use a different machine to try out this. I suspect some setting in your ansible.cfg may be wrong

Answer (score 12):

If you can ssh from your control host to your target hosts (i.e., ec2 instances), but "ansible all -m ping" fails with a publickey error message, then you need to modify the ansible.cfg file in your working (playbook) directory.

```
[defaults]
inventory = ./hosts-dev
remote_user = <SSH_USERNAME>
private_key_file = /path_to/<SSH_KEY>.pem
```

For me the key was to add private_key_file = /home/ubuntu/.ssh/my_key.pem

Also, make sure to modify the properties of your key file, for example:
    chmod 400 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/my_key.pem

Otherwise, AWS will reject the key as "too open", but that won't come through in the error message.
You can test this by using a direct connection from your control host using:

ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/my_key.pem ubuntu@Internal_IP_Address_of_Target_Machine

Comment: private key permissions should be 600, public 644.